# jquery / javascript not picking up value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically alter a variable with the "name" attribute from a link - code below...

```
       <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dp1">

       <a href="javascript:;" class="tab" name="1,2">test button</a>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pickable = { dp1: [4,5,6] };

    $(".tab").click(function () { 
        var test = $(this).attr("name").split(",");
        pickable = { dp1:  test  };
    });

    $(".datepicker").each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
                var day = date.getDay(), days = pickable[this.id];
                return [$.inArray(day, days) > -1, ""];
            },
        });
    });

});​
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work??

Comment: what do you get? the string "1, 2" instead?

Comment: not sure to be honest... how do i find out?

Comment: The var "test" value is always a string

Comment: and i need it to be an array?? is that right?

Comment: @joberror: Actually, from the code above, `test` is an array containing the single string `"1, 2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var pickable = ["2","3","4","5"];

function closedDays(date){
    var sDate = date.getDay().toString();
    if ($.inArray(sDate, pickable) == -1) return [false,"",""];
    else return [true, ""];
}

$(".tab").click(function () { 
   pickable =  $(this).attr("name").split(",");
     closedDays;
});

$(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay:  closedDays
    });
});
});​
```

You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/ZKW3b/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the function passed to `click` is not being executed, check whether that code is being interpreted before the html.

Try wrapping the code in the `ready` function:

```
$(function () {
    var pickable = { dp1: [4, 5, 6] };
    $(".tab").click(function () { 
        var test = [ $(this).attr("name") ];
        pickable = { dp1:  test  };
    });
});
```

---

If the problem is that you want the string value of `name`, `"1, 2"`, to be an array, you need to change your code a bit:

```
var pickable = { dp1: [4, 5, 6] };

$(".tab").click(function () { 
    var test = $(this).attr("name").split(",");
    pickable = { dp1:  test  };
});
```

Now, the value `"1, 2"` is being split by the `,` token and seperated into an array of values: `["1", "2"]`

Comment: I have already done that, just didn't include it in the code i posted. sorry

Comment: I see what you're saying but it still doesn't work... here's a link to the code put in context, perhaps that'll work... http://jsfiddle.net/BhzE5/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to have var pickable available anywhere in your code, you might want to use, [jquery data](http://docs.jquery.com/Data). You can try something like this:

```
    $(document).data('pickable', { dp1: [4, 5, 6] } );
    $(".tab").click(function () { 
        var test = $(this).attr("name").split(',');
        $(document).data('pickable', { dp1:  test  });
    });
```

Comment: Your example will create an array within an array: `[["1", "2"]]`